# How to Get Dynamic url from spring to angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, url, angular7

My backend is of spring boot and front-end is of Angular 7 . I want the spring-boot local server address to get dynamically in Angular while routing .
So if the port address in Spring boot server is changed it should also reflect in Angular ?
Any idea how to do that.

I tried using window.location.host but it reflects server address of Angular (i.e. localhost//4200 ) instead of (localhost//8080).

```
_url ='http://localhost:8080/home/delete/';
_updateurl ='http://localhost:8080/home/delete/';
```

instead it should show like

url=SpringBoot+'home/delete'

Answer (score 0):

You should use Angular [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute). It will return the relative url where your Angular application is. It will not take into account where you deployed this app.

You can observe your current URL:

```js
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => {
    // Do something with your current url when it changes
});
```

Or just get an instant snap shot of the url:

```js
const snapShot = this.activatedRoute.snapshot;
```

Comment: This will get me the current url . I want server side url e.g. http://localhost:8080/home/login  that too dynamically . So if i change spring port to 7000 it should reflect http://localhost:7000/home/login or something like that

Answer (score 0):

So People I got a solution to my question . So far I have not found a single way that angular would scan the change in backend port and change it accordingly but what we can do is use Environment.ts from angular 
So basically we just need to put

```
export const environment = {  
 Url: 'http://localhost:8080',
debugMode: false
};
```

and wherever you need it just import the environment and add 
    `console.log(environment.Url+'abc');`

and it will work .